# Assigning script to multiple objects

Tags: unity, c#

So I have multiple gameobjects that needs to be interactable and I've put them all in one gameobject container. But the thing is I still have to attach the script into each of the gameobjects that needs to be interactable for it to work and that seems kinda iffy when a scenario comes that I have to add more gameObjects.

Is it possible to just put the script in the container object? I tried this on my container object and I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong.

```
public GameObject spriteHandler;
GameObject sprite1;
GameObject sprite2;
GameObject sprite3;
private void Start()
{
    sprite1 = spriteHandler.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
    sprite2 = spriteHandler.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject;
    sprite3 = spriteHandler.transform.GetChild(2).gameObject;
}
void OnMouseDown()
{
    Debug.Log("Clicked");

}
```

Comment: What behaviour would you like the parent script to have? Right now this looks pretty placeholder, so it's hard to guess where you're planning to develop it from here.

Comment: Basically what's going to be in OnMouseDown() is a method from another script that opens up the dialogue when you click  the sprite. That works when I assign the script with OnMouseDown() on the gameobjects individually. I'm just looking for a way so I only need to assign this script with OnMouseDown() on the parent object. Maybe I should use events?

Comment: And is it the same dialogue no matter which sprite you click, or a different dialogue depending on the sprite? Be sure your question contains a *complete* description of what you need, so you don't get incomplete answers.

Comment: My bad. Yeah, it's basically the same dialogue. What sprite you click doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your overall goals for what the gameobject is doing. But from what you have said - the preferred method would be to make the Gameobjects prefabs - and attach the interactable script to the prefabs (so as you Instantiate them - each one will have the script attached.).

Here is the documentation on Prefabs & Instantiating Prefabs:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html